python selenium how can I create a personal class with atributes of webdriverWait? I need POLL_FREQUENCY so my test can run smoothly in every step
I have this class:
class LoginPage(WebDriverWait,BaseWait,BaseStep):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)
        self.driver = driver

And I need to inject the driver with WebDriverWait(timeout=10, poll_frequency=1) for example.
I need to use this driver through all my test.
I need to inject it directly to self.driver, please can you help me?
I cannot do:
class LoginPage(WebDriverWait,BaseWait,BaseStep):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)
        self.driver = driver
        self.webdriver = WebDriverWait(driver)

because I would be using another driver, please can you help me?
